# <option> element is not append in his <select> parents but just below

Tags: javascript, html, append, appendchild, web-development-server

I have a little problem with my JavaScript.
I'm trying to appendChild an `<option>` to a `<select>` parent. But instead of insert it between:

```
<select>
 <option></option>
</select>
```

actually I have this result:

```
<select></select>
<option></option>
```

After having visited a lot of links (a lot about jQuery that I'm not using, I probably should learn about), I still don't understand my mistakes.

This is my codes:
**the HTML code**

```
<form class="formulaireAjout"  action="/www/libs/ajoutStageExistant-php.php" method="post">
    <h1>Si on peut se faciliter la tache ...</h1>
    <p id="ref_entreprise">
        <label for="ref_entrepriseSelect">L'entreprise est déja referencée ? </label>
        <select id="ref_entrepriseSelect" onchange="request(this);">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="oui">Oui</option>
            <option value="non">Non</option>
        </select>
        <span id="loader" style="display: none;">
            <img style="width:20px" src="/www/images/loader.gif" alt="loading">
        </span>
    </p>

    <p id="entreprises">
        <select id="entrepriseSelect" name="entrepriseSelect" onchange="requestMission(this);"></select>
    </p>

    <p id="mission" style="display: none;">
        <select id="missionSelect" name="missionSelect" onchange="requestAjoutMission(this);"></select>
        <span id="loaderMission" style="display: none;">
            <img style="width:20px" src="/www/images/loader.gif" alt="loading">
        </span>
    </p>

     <p id="filiere" style="display:none">Filière
        <label for="filiere"></label>
        <select name="filiere" id="filiere">
            <option>Choisissez une Filière</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p id="specialite" style="display:none">Spécialité
        <label for="specialite"></label>
        <select name="specialite" id="specialite">
            <option class="" value="-">-</option>
        </select> 
    </p>
</form>
```

**The javascript**

```
//List to add in select "filiere"
var filieres = [ 
{
    code:"ETI",
    nom: "Sciences du numérique"
},
{
    code: "CGP",
    nom: "Chimie Génie des Procédés"
},
{
    code: "IRC",
    nom: "Informatique et réseaux de communication"
}
];



function requestAjoutMission(oSelect)
{
var value = oSelect.options[oSelect.selectedIndex].value; //Le     num_mission qui est la value dans le seclet
var filiereSelect = document.getElementById("filiere");
var majeureElt = document.getElementById("specialite");


if(value === "0")
{
    filiereSelect.style.display = "block";
    majeureElt.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("stage").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("duree").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("description").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("loaderMission").style.display = "none";

    //Fill the select with options 
    filieres.forEach(function (filiere) {
            filiereSelect.appendChild(creerEltOption(filiere.nom,filiere.code));
    });

    filiereSelect.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        var majeures = getMajeures(e.target.value);
        majeureElt.innerHTML=""; //Vidage de la liste
        //Ajout de chaque majeure à la liste
        majeures.forEach(function (majeure){
            majeureElt.appendChild(creerEltOption(majeure,majeure));
        });
    });
}
}
//Return list for the select majeure function to the option selected      in the previous select
function getMajeures(filiere){

switch(filiere){
    case "ETI" : 
        return ["Image", "Electronique", "Robotique", "Réseau", "Informatique"];
    case "CGP":
        return ["Maj1", "Maj2"];
    case "IRC": 
        return ["pas de majeurs"];
    default: 
        return [];
}
} 


//Create Option element in HTML 
function creerEltOption(texte, valeur){
    var element = document.createElement("option");
    element.value = valeur;
    var oInner = document.createTextNode(texte);
    element.appendChild(oInner);

    return element;
}
```

Sorry for all this code, but as I don't know where the error is from I think it's better to show you more than less.

I also joined pictures of the current result on the web page and in the firebug of firefox:

[Visual resutl on the web page : option are not in the select input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgODw.png)

[HTML Result in the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzSy7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem, you have two elements with the same id.

```
<p id="specialite" style="display:none">Spécialité
<select name="specialite" id="specialite">
```

ids are singular and you have multiple elements with the same id.

So the browser you are using is selecting the p and appending the elements there. You had a naming pattern for other selects, you should do that for this last two.

---

Also you are empting th html of a select with

```
majeureElt.innerHTML=""
```

A better way would be to set the length to zero or call removeChild() in a while loop.

```
majeureElt.options.length=0;
```

And personally I would add options like this, but appending them is also fine.

```
majeures.forEach(function (majeure, index){
    majeureElt.options[index] = new Option(majeure,majeure);
});
```

Comment: Oh I didn't saw this one coming ! Twice the same id ...Good to have an outside look on it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @epascarello . 
Could you tell me why it's better to emptying the select element with this method rather than the barbaric method ? (I think the answer is in the question anyway).